# Offline Android Gradle Plugin 3.5.0 in Intellij IDEA 2019

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have downloaded the offline version of android gradle plugin 3.5.0 but I have no idea how to install it in Idea. I've tried the normal plugin installation procedure but it's not showing up in the plugins list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the procedure to follow: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#download_offline

After that, you have to open your project build.gradle file and change this line:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}
```

to version that you have in this folder: `C:\Users\<username>\.android\manual-offline-m2\android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01\com\android\tools\build\gradle`